# How to restrict access of a content to certain users in drupal?

Tags: mysql, drupal

In my drupal site I need to restrict the access of a content to certain users. I have a set of items and each item is a content. Each user will be assigned to a certain content. In my mysql table there are two fields, `userid` and `contentid`. According to this how will I restrict the access to each user? I.e. when a user tries to access the content, it should be checked whether the user has its access. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. Node access user reference module will do the needful.
https://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference